# Active Admin Search Status / Current Filters panel not using filter label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I have an active admin filter using ransack:

```
filter :address_state_or_address_city_cont, as: :string, label: "Address"
```

The problem in the Search Status panel is it's not using the label:
[image]

Saying 'State' here is wrong since we're also querying address city.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug that's fixed already: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/5886